# Why i am getting output as "This is String" instead of "This is not String"

Tags: php

Q. I am getting output of below code as "this is string" instead of "this is not a string" why so?

```
<?php
$abc=0;

    if($abc == "str")
    {
        echo "This is string";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "This is not a string";
}
?>
```

Comment: Use is_string() function or data type check use ===

Comment: $abc = 0 // false. First condition return false.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274307/very-illogical-php-value-comparisons/3274413) and many, many others

Answer (score 3):

It's better to compare using `===` which will also type check the compared variables.

```
if($abc === "str")
{
    echo "This is string";
}
else
{
    echo "This is not a string";
}
```

This will work as expected.
See [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for a PHP type comparison tables. There you see that a "Loose comparisons with ==" between e.g. `0` (int) and `"php"` (string) will return `true`. Which is not what one would expect.

Comment: but how does it internally works ? i know about the difference between == and === but i want to know that how this code will internally work.

Comment: The php manual [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) as cited by @Ihor Burlachenko makes it clear. If you use `==` then there will be a type conversion. This way `"str"` is converted to 0. Just try `var_dump((int)"foo")` and you will see that the it will output `0`. This value is then compared to `0` and returns true. 
With `===` there will be ***NO*** type conversion.
If you really want to know whats going on, you should have a look at the php source code itself.

Comment: Ohkk sir Thank you so much..! My doubt is clear.

Answer (score 1):

According to [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

`"str"` is converted to `0` when you compare them together using `==` operator. To make your code work you have to use `===` operator.

> The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

Comment: but why str is converted in to 0 ? why not in any other number . if i write $abc="1" then it converts to in numeric 1 but why does str converts to 0.

Comment: This is how type conversion in PHP works. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Have a look at [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Comment: Thank you sir..my doubt is clear..

Answer (score -1):

Use `is_string()` to find whether the type of a variable is string

```
<?php
    $abc=0;
    if(is_string($abc))
    {
        echo "This is string";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "This is not a string";
    }
?>
```

Comment: but how does it internally works ? i know about is_string() but i want to know that how this code will internally work.